# Sort command nuances

Tags: sorting

I need to sort data with alphanumerical id's. Sorting with sort -n -k1,1 and variations of that command do not provide results sorted in numerical order. Any ideas? Need to sort on the first column.

Data

```
w51591  w53646  0.87389
w1874   w1878   -0.80693
w40054  w40193  -0.89137
w51571  w56635  -0.43085
w1728   w53651  0.9258
w10567  w40186  -0.9174
w10569  w40038  -0.916
```

Current output of sort -n -k1,1

```
w10567  w40186  -0.9174
w10569  w40038  -0.916
w1728   w53651  0.9258
w1874   w1878   -0.80693
w40054  w40193  -0.89137
w51571  w56635  -0.43085
w51591  w53646  0.87389
```

Also, is there a way to sort on the first column, then by the second if I have repeated id's in the first column?

Thanks and Happy Holidays.

Comment: Is "sort -n -k1,1" a bash command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort on the first column correctly:

```
sort -k 2 -n -t 'w' input.txt
```

This changes the field separator to 'w' which is kind of a hack to strip off that leading character from your input. The number you're sorting on in the first column then becomes field 2 (hence `-k 2`).

I don't know of a way to accomplish the second part of your question (sorting also on the second column) with `sort`, I think you might need a more complicated solution for that, like a short Perl script.

EDIT: See 1_CR's answer below for a way to sort on both columns.

Comment: Well that worked perfect, thanks! For whatever reason the second column appears to be sorted in order as well in my larger file. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

you could specify the start character for the sort field as 2 to skip the `w`

```
sort -n -k1.2,1
```

To sort by the first field and then the second

```
sort  -k1.2,1n -k2.2,2n
```